# R script column selection different result

Tags: r

I have a data frame like the image. why when I use df[,test] it outputed the first column value while when I try test=="Yield (%)"  is true?

I did test on

```
Browse[2]> test=="Yield (%)" 
[1] TRUE 
Browse[2]> df[,"Yield (%)"]  
 [1] 67.283951 67.283951 67.283951
> 
> Browse[2]> df[,test]   [1] Lot_726.1 Lot_726.1 Lot_726.1 Lot_726.1
> Lot_726.1 Lot_726.1 Lot_726.1 Lot_726.1 Lot_726.1*
```

[image]

Comment: So you do mean data.table rather than data.frame, right? A data.table has different indexing properties. Maybe try `df[,test, with=FALSE]` and then maybe read a basic introduction to data.tables. In the future, please post [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) rather than images of data.

Comment: Hi, I actually imported df as data frame. here is how i imported it                                                                                                       df<-read.delim("zonedata.txt",check.names=FALSE)

Comment: Well, you said data table which is a very different type of object. You really need to prepare a self contained, minimal reproducible example so we can see what's going in. The link i provided before has many tips on how to do that.

Comment: I figured out the issue, when I imported the data frame it auto changed the string to factor. so when I do df[,test] it actually returned the df[,1]